# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgbAlert with angular2-meteor and ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular2-meteor

I'm running a meteor project using angular as the front end and I can't seem to figure out how to get @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap to import into my project correctly. Here is my setup...

Meteor Version: 1.6, Angular Version: 5.1.3, @ng-bootstrap/bootstrap: 1.0.0-beta.9, Bootstrap: 4.0.0 beta 3 (CSS through CDN)

**client/app/app.module.ts**: (cut down version)

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent} from './app-component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [OtherModules, NgbModule.forRoot()],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
...
```

**client/main.ts**:

```
import '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

I can't figure out why the module fails to import.
I'm sure it's a simple problem that I just can't figure out. Thank you for your help!

The Full Error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for NgbAlert: (?).
    at syntaxError (modules.js?
hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:49950)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (modules.js?
hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:65156)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (modules.js?
hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:64991)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (modules.js?
hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:64477)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (modules.js?
hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:65304)
    at modules.js?hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:64774
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (modules.js?
hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:64774)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (modules.js?
hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:64589)
    at modules.js?hash=677f7440cc3c0fd0f024fe4055f104c52a9d1865:64687
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar error here [Can't load @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852682/cant-load-ng-bootstrap-ng-bootstrap-with-angular/50858966#50858966) with a solution I've found after several days beating my head against the wall...

Edit: Added answer

I added require('reflect-metadata'); on top of my renderer.ts .

```
require('reflect-metadata');
let BrowserModule = require('@angular/platform-browser').BrowserModule;
let UpgradeModule = require('@angular/upgrade/static').UpgradeModule;
let NgbModule = require('@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap').NgbModule;
Placing it somewhere else doesn't make it work.
```

After some investigation, I came with that the problem was caused due to a reflection error within the JIT compiler when trying to load ng-bootstrap modules.

Comment: Why the downvoting?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 0):

I dodn't see how you are including the `NgbAlert` entity itself in your code... Does it look like –

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdAlertBasic } from './alert-basic'; // this

@NgModule({
    imports: [OtherModules, NgbModule.forRoot()],
    declarations: [App, NgbdAlertBasic] // and this
    // ...
})
```

? Full example could be obtained [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/alert/demos/basic/plnkr.html). Each ng-bootstrap entity you are going to use in your App needs to be included in your `@NgModule` "declarations". If this doesn't help, you need to update your post and show the exact code that produces your error.

---

**Update**. Per official [angular-meteor tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrap):

> Meteor supports NPM packages (starting from 1.3)... a file named
>   package.json was created - this file contains the project's npm
>   dependencies... To install the current project dependencies, type in
>   the command line npm install.

So, in addition to `NgModule` changes I put above, the `ng-bootstrap` package needs to be installed via npm:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Comment: That's the thing. I'm actually not trying to use NgbAlert anywhere thus I'm not declaring it anywhere. In your example, I noticed you have a config.js file, but the only config file I have is ts-config.json. Maybe I dont have something setup correctly? I'm using the meteor cli for everything.

Comment: @Nate Im my example the only thing I have is `ng-bootstrap` in my `./node_modules` installed via `npm`. No additional configuration (okay, one line could appear in `package.json`). I believe 1) you need it to be installed; 2) you need it to be included in your Angular AppModule. Otherwise you will not be able to use it in your App.

Comment: I have done both of those steps and still get the NgbAlert error, even in a brand new project where the only thing I have done is install ng-bootstrap through npm and imported it into my AppModule. I'm totally lost.

Comment: @Nate Could you add please full error message? we need to know who is responsible for the error. Also, provide please a temlate of usage from you App (it should look like `<ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">...</ngb-alert>`).

Comment: I updated with the full error message. I'm not using <ngb-alert> in ANY of my code. In fact, I'm not using any ng-bootstrap directives in my code. I'm getting this error by simply trying to import the ng-bootstrap module into a brand new, blank project.

Comment: @Nate Ok! so what is `NgbAlert` in your App? where is it mentioned in your App code/configs?

Comment: @Nate It looks like typical circular dependency issue with no correlation to real ng-bootstrap. Need to trace all `NgbAlert` entries.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get it... I'm not referencing <ngb-alert> in ANY of my code or configs, yet for whatever reason I am getting this error. The only thing I reference is importing NgbModule and calling NgbModule.forRoot() in app.module.ts.

If I search for NgbAlert in my whole project, I get 0 results.

Comment: @Nate That's bad... push your project sources to GitHub/Bitbucket/whatever and give me a link.

Comment: Pull this and let me know what you think! https://github.com/knsonier/bootstrapAngularMeteorTest

Comment: @Nate I tried your repo and was not able to run the App, I stopped much earlier than your NgbAlert issue occurred. I tried to make it work for some time, but I failed (endless incompatibilities, all damn slow etc). I also tried `meteor create simple-todos` and that App worked. For me there's too many magic with Meteor. You may try [this](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor-base) starter, it looks like an actual thing. Or just throw away Meteor and build your App with Angular CLI...

Comment: Can you try making a new meteor project, installing the angular dependencies, then try installing ng-bootstrap? Not sure why my example didn't work for you. I pulled it back out of git and compiled it just fine.

Comment: @Nate I'm afraid it's not possible because it takes too much time. Try to open a ticket [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues). Or do a research with [this proj](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor-base) (`meteor create --example angular2-boilerplate`)...

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came to was to enable AOT.  The issue seems to pop up in the Angular JIT code, but it's able to properly handle the code if the Meteor code is pre-compiled.

I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768171/cant-find-a-datepicker-that-plays-nicely-with-angular-meteor/50840109#50840109) hoping that I might be able to find a solution.  Unfortunately, it was just downvoted, sooo...not quite successful.  But I kept digging and found the AOT solution.  Hopefully someone will be able to explain why this works and possibly help us to find the root cause!