# Can't find a datepicker that plays nicely with angular-meteor

Tags: angular, meteor, ng-bootstrap, angular-meteor

I've tried to add a bunch of different datepicker libraries to my project:

- Meteor 1.7
- Angular 6
- Bootstrap 4

For most of the packages that are intended for Angular I get an error during import on startup.  The error normally looks similar.  Here is the exact error from ng-bootstrap:

`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgbAlert: (?).`

In the case of that error I have not included an `NgbAlert` anywhere, it's solely from adding `NgbModule.forRoot()` so don't let the alert confuse you, the issue definitely has something to do with importing the module.

I've tried:

- ng-pick-datetime
- Ngx-Bootstrap
- ng-bootstrap
- and some others

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Semi-Solution**

Set AOT=1 in meteor environment variables.

**Discussion**

I was able to get ng-bootstrap working by sym-linking the library (to ensure that it is transpiled) and then building Meteor with AOT enabled.

I narrowed down the original failure to an area in the Angular JIT compiler code.  I really don't know a ton about how Angular-Meteor's angular-compiler code works, in relation to Angular's normal compile flow, so I can't really get to the root of the problem.  If anyone can provide a lower level explanation, I'd really appreciate it!

---

**Update**

In a different, but similar question a better semi-solution was provided by [ironmanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9940353/ironmanu) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142615/uncaught-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-ngbalert-with-angular2-meteor-a/50840253#50840253).  It's still not a perfect solution but it's a usable bandaid.

The solution is to add `require('reflect-metadata');` to the top of the module imports in `app.module.ts`.  This solves the issue during JIT.  I'm not sure why the Angular compiler doesn't inherently take care of this issue, but this does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I use angular material’s datepicker. It works well with angular-meteor.

I also use ngbootstrap in my app but find it more troublesome than angular material’s components. I’m gradually replacing most components with materials over time